# Call order of h:commandLink action and f:ajax listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces

Here is my markup:

```html
<h:commandLink value="#{partial}" action="#{hello.setCurrentPartial(partial)}">
    <f:ajax render="include" listener="#{hello.renderFragments}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I tried to run this page in Mojarra-2.2.8(wildfly 8.2.0.Final built-in) and MyFaces-2.2.7(installed as guided [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddAnyNewJSFImplementationOrVersionToWildFly)). Surprisingly, when the link is clicked, mojarra calls `hello.renderFragments` first and then `hello.setCurrentPartial`, but MyFaces takes the opposite order, i.e., `hello.setCurrentPartial` is called first.

So my question is whether there is a definition of the call order of action and ajax listener in JSF Spec. Which implementation is correct if the order is defined?

Comment: This is indeed unexpected. As workaround, move `<f:ajax listener>` to `<h:commandLink actionListener>`. I'll ask the JSF spec guys about this difference.

Comment: @BalusC I guess the mojarra behavior is the desired one (please correct me as I'm not really sure), shouldn't listeners get invoked before the action method ?

Comment: @Tarik: I can't find a reference in the spec about this behavior, but Mojarra behavior is indeed more intuitive/natural/expected. First listeners and then finally action, exactly like how actionListener/action work. I left the EG a [mail](https://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces-spec-public/lists/jsr372-experts/archive/2015-03/message/12).

Comment: @BalusC Ok great, BTW you just got a first reply

Comment: @Tarik: Yup, was just my colleague mentioning an agreement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [EG discussion](https://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces-spec-public/lists/jsr372-experts/archive/2015-03/message/12), there's agreement on Mojarra behavior being correct as it's in line with how `actionListener`/`action` work. The MyFaces guy has created an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3960) on it and it's expected that this will be fixed for next MyFaces release. And, the JSF spec should be more explicit in this, this will be worked on.

In the meanwhile, if you want to have the same behavior in both Mojarra and MyFaces as to the method invocation order, move the `<f:ajax listener>` to `<h:commandLink actionListener>`.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{partial}" actionListener="#{hello.renderFragments}" action="#{hello.setCurrentPartial(partial)}">
    <f:ajax render="include" />
</h:commandLink>
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)

Comment: Quick response and thorough explanation of the problem and the solution both as always.  If there is only one reason to do JSF, it is @BalusC.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for questioning this discrepancy, it only makes JSF better.